# Finding and replacing content between brackets with jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, preg-replace, brackets

I have a requirement to place text between brackets using jQuery; the content will be updated once an action occurs e.g. search.

The structure is:

```
<h2>Placeholder Text Placeholder Text Placeholder Text ()</h2>
```

Comment: can you define the question better?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [indexOf](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#indexof) method:

```
text = $("h2").text();
pos1 = text.indexOf("(");
pos2 = text.indexOf(")");
newText = text.substring(0, pos1 + 1) + myText + text.substring(pos2);
```

The above assumes that one and only one pair of brackets is to be found in the text.

Comment: Thanks but this won't work as it will continually prefix the new count before the old count, I need it to replace the content of () with the new count number. I should mention that the state of the string could contain numbers already; at variable length.

Comment: What if the closing bracket is before the opening bracket?

Comment: Use the following sanity test: if (pos1 > -1 && pos2 > pos1)